# Intent Service do not get started when called from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

I am working on an app in which on receiving a message i need to start a service. But my Intent service is not running. Here is what I am doing:

**Broadcast Receiver:**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    this.con=context;
    Toast.makeText(context,"Broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int i=0;i<messages.length;i++)
    {
        sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
    }

    String smsFrom = sms[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress().toString();

    Intent in= new Intent(context, ResponseService.class);
    in.putExtra("sender",smsFrom);
    context.startService(in);
}
```

**IntentService:**

```
public class ResponseService extends IntentService 
{
    public ResponseService(String name) 
        {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Notify", "In Response Service");
        getCurrentLocation();
        }
}
```

I don't get anything in the Log file. can anybody please help me understanding the problem? Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I already have declared both broadcast receiver and service in manifest.xml as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadCastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".ResponseService" />
```

Moreover I again tried to run the app and after some time the app force closed giving a java.lang.instantiationexception
Can somebody please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be: Is your broadcast receiver working? Is the toast in your broadcast receiver being displayed?
Second question: Did you declare your intent service in manifest? You can do so the following way:

```
<service android:name="yourPackage.ResponseService" >
```

Comment: yes the toast is being displayed and I have declared the receiver in manifest. receiver works perfectly fine.

Comment: Then your intent service is not working. Be sure to declare `ResponseService` too, like I declared in my answer.

Comment: I have declared that as well

Comment: Did you declare the package correctly? Maybe you have your `ResponseService` in a different package?

Comment: No, I have only one package in my app

Answer (score 1):

The exception, java.lang.InstantiationException really solved my problem. I was missing a zero argument public constructor. I just changed

```
public ResponseService(String name) 
        {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Into:

```
public ResponseService() 
        {
        super("ResponseService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

And now it's working really well. Hope it might help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

A WakefulBroadcastReceiver is a special type of broadcast receiver that takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for your app. It passes off the work of processing the SMS to a your ResponseService (IntentService), while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep in the transition, so your Intent Service will run correctly.

```
public class YourReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that ResponseService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                ResponseService.class.getName());

        this.con=context;
        Toast.makeText(context,"Broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for(int i=0;i<messages.length;i++)
        {
            sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
        }

        String smsFrom = sms[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress().toString();

        Intent in= new Intent(context, ResponseService.class);
        in.putExtra("sender",smsFrom)
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And your IntentService will be like:

```
 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  

            //Do something

        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        YourReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done alarms before but you can easily forget to declare it along your wakefulbroadcastreceiver in your manifest.xml.