# How to start an IntentService from a WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I have an application, which you should be able to recreate entirely and very easily with the code I'll post in this question. Here's the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcasttest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.TestReceiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>

        <intentservice 
            android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </intentservice>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see, the contains an activity, a (wakeful) broadcast receiver and an intentservice, all in the same package. The activity gets started at launch, here's the code:

```
package com.example.broadcasttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(this, TestReceiver.class));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This succesfully triggers the `onReceive` function of `TestReceiver`.

```
package com.example.broadcasttest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class TestReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Intent service = new Intent("com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService");
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MonitorService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

}
```

This is where things go wrong though, I placed a breakpoint in the `onReceive` function and it definitely gets called. However, the `MonitorService` class never gets reached. I placed a breakpoint in the `onHandleEvent` function, but it seems like it never gets that far. Here's the code for this class:

```
package com.example.broadcasttest;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MonitorService extends IntentService {

    public MonitorService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public MonitorService()
    {
        super("MonitorService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            TestReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

As you can tell from the commented line in the `TestReceiver` class, I've tried using an implicit intent instead of an explicit one. I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937679/intent-service-do-not-get-started-when-called-from-a-broadcast-receiver) and tried everything mentioned there. Am I missing something here? I'm running this on an emulator (Nexus7 API L).

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm sorry , what exactly is the purpose of these codes?What does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no tag as `<intentservice>` in [**Application Manifest**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). `IntentService` is a subclass of `Service`, so you need to declare it as service in manifest.

---

Change

```
<intentservice 
    android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService"
    android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService" />
        </intent-filter>
</intentservice>
```

to

```
<service 
    android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService"
    android:enabled="true" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.MonitorService" />
       </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks, if only I had known that it was that simple.
I wonder why I didn't get any sort of error though.